# How to be able to pass individual element and [] both to param

Tags: c#, .net, parameters

I have a function which will take some byte(s) OR byte[] and bundle them all up in a byte[] and return. I placed my choice on params keyword in c#  but not sure how to make it accept both individual byte(s) and byte[] both as parameters:

my sample code below:

```
public byte[] Construct(params byte[] values)
       {
           List<byte> packet = new List<byte>();
           for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
           {
               packet.Add(values[i]);
           }

           return packet.ToArray();
       }
```

Please not that construct should be able to accept both individual byte(s) and byte[]

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?  Can the calling code just as easily send in an array of one byte?

Comment: As it stands now your proc can receive individual bytes or an array of bytes but not both on the same argument

Comment: @Steve: yes correct, is there any way to change it so that it can take both when we don't how many individual bytes and how many array are coming IF any?

Answer (score 1):

`params` should be the last parameter in the method definition, like this:

```
public byte[] Construct(byte arg1, byte arg2, params byte[] values)
```

From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx):

> No additional parameters are permitted after the params keyword in a method declaration, and only one params keyword is permitted in a method declaration.

If you want to pass one byte array, then individual bytes after that array you can use this signature:

```
 public byte[] Construct(byte[] array, params byte[] values)
```

This version expects at least one byte array and then one or more bytes.For example you can call it like this, just with byte array:

```
Construct(new byte[] { 10,20,30,40 });
```

Or like this, all of them are valid:

```
Construct(new byte[] { 10,20,30,40 }, 11);
Construct(new byte[] { 10,20,30,40 }, 11,22,33); 
Construct(new byte[] { 10,20,30,40 }, 11,22,33,44);
Construct(new byte[] { 10,20,30,40 }, new byte[] { 11,22,33,44 });
```

But this is not valid:

```
 Construct(new byte[] { 10,20}, new byte[] { 11,22 }, 77);
```

Because first parameter is `byte` array, second is `params`.And there is no third parameter.So basically `params byte[]` means: `zero` or `more` bytes, or just *one byte array.*

Comment: But what if I dont know what will be the number of individual bytes coming?

Comment: then use method overloading.

Comment: What the `params` keyword gives you is that flexibility - you can pass from 0 up to a theoretically infinite number of bytes.  This is explained in the documentation linked to in @Selman22's answer.  From that documentation - "You can send a comma-separated list of arguments of the type specified in the parameter declaration or an array of arguments of the specified type. You also can send no arguments. If you send no arguments, the length of the params list is zero."

Comment: @Californicated I think you really confused about params.Please read the documentation first, `params byte[]`  doesn't allow you to pass a byte array to your function.it allows you to pass zero or more bytes, then they will converted to byte array by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you want a method that will accept individual `byte` values and a single `byte[]` then your current definition is already sufficient.

```
Construct(42, 13);  // Works
Construct(new byte[] { 42, 13 });  // Also works
```

If you want to accept both `byte[]` and `byte` values into the same method call then you will need to add overloads to accommodate that.

```
byte[] Construct(byte b1, byte[] b2)
byte[] Construct(byte b1, byte b2, byte[] b3)
// etc ...
```

Other than that the only issue with the current definition is that it's unnecessarily allocation heavy.

Firstly the method body inefficiently allocates array values.  The `List<byte>` type is going to dynamically allocate `byte[]` values as they are added.  After all those allocations are done another final `byte[]` will be allocated in the `ToArray` call.  In this particular case you know the **exact** size of the final array hence it's more efficient to just allocate it directly and avoid `List<byte>`

```
byte[] packet = new byte[values.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) {
  packet[i] = values[i];
}
return packet;
```

The second inefficiency is that the calling code will allocate an array for passing a relatively small number of parameters.  If this is actually common then you can avoid the array allocation by having non-params overloads

```
public byte[] Construct(byte b1) { 
  return new[] { b1 };
}

public byte[] Construct(byte b1, byte b2) { 
  return new[] { b1, b2 };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to let the functions argument be `params byte[][]`.
Then if you would have to pass a single byte you could pass it as an array of length one.

LinqPad example:

```
void Main()
{
    Construct(new byte[] { 10, 20 }, new byte[] { 255 }).Dump();
}

public byte[] Construct(params byte[][] values)
{
    return values.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
}
```

Here `255` is a single byte, but 'wrapped' in an array.
This prints the following:

```
10
20
255
```